# General Question concerning Microsoft Power BI Embedded

Tags: web

I'm researching Microsoft Power BI in order to see if it would be a good fit for my organization. It's important that we can use the graphs made in Power BI on an external facing web application. I've watched videos over Power BI Embedded and all I can find are the solutions that look like an iframe, like a Widget. I want the flexibility to control each component of the report, put the items where they need to get in the web page, but maintain the interactions and data between these elements. Is that possible with Power BI? Does anyone have examples of data visualizations on external facing web applications that aren't wrapped up in an iframe? Any recommended documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pick out reporting elements in a Power BI report and embedded them into a web page. The Power BI Javascript api demo, does show some examples

https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html